# Show mpf_t in console

Tags: c++, windows, gmp

I make simple additing in really big number so I use GMP library (c++). I have problem with comunicate with users it means I can't use cin and cout this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main() {

  mpf_class x("7612058254738945");
  mpf_class y("9263591128439081");
  mpf_class z = x+y;
  std::cout<< z<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and I have:

> D:\gmp-6.0.0a\gmp-6.0.0\gmpxx.h|1954|undefined reference to
>   `operator<<(std::ostream&, __mpf_struct const*)'| ||error: ld returned
>   1 exit status|

What i should do?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing `libgmpxx` from the link line - no idea how you're compiling it to determine the relevant command line for this.

Comment: Looks like you need to link in the appropriate library.

Comment: so what I should do?

Comment: Add `-lgmpxx` to your compile line